# Getting error while implementing KNN algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

New to stackoverflow and also programming, I'm from statistics background below is the implementation of KNN algorithm. Getting an error 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

These are the other errors I got. Thank you in advance for answering.

> File "knn.py", line 78, in 
>       main()
>
> File "knn.py", line 71, in main
>       neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
>
> File "knn.py", line 33, in getNeighbors
>       dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
>
> File "knn.py", line 26, in euclideanDistance
>       distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)

```
import csv
import random
import math
import pandas
import numpy

def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):

    filename = 'data1.csv'
    raw_data = open(filename, 'rt')
    reader = csv.reader(raw_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    dataset = list(reader)


    for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
        for y in range(4):
            dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
        if random.random() < split:
            trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
        else:
            testSet.append(dataset[x])

def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length):
        distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testInstance)-1
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors

def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = neighbors[x][-1]
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]

def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] == predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0

def main():
# prepare data
    trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    split = 0.67
    loadDataset('data1.csv', split, trainingSet, testSet)
    print ('Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet)))
    print ('Test set: ' + repr(len(testSet)))
# generate predictions
    predictions=[]
    k = 3
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
        print('> predicted=' + repr(result) + ', actual=' + repr(testSet[x][-1]))
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: ' + repr(accuracy) + '%')

main()
```

Comment: After you call `loadDataset`, can you look into result of `print(type(trainingSet[0]))`

Comment: The type is list

Answer (score 0):

Vamsi,

I noticed you are using numpy and pandas. While, I'm working on debugging I did want to recommend one more awesome package, sci-kit learn.

They have an implementation of KNN already built in:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

EDIT: 
I beleive there is a casting issue on line 26. It appears you are trying to subtract 2 strings. I think this may solve your issue if yout are working with integer data

```
def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
     distance = 0
     for x in range(length):
         distance += pow((int(instance1[x]) - int(instance2[x])), 2)
     return math.sqrt(distance)
```

If you are working with floating point data than the following would work:

```
distance += pow((float(instance1[x]) - float(instance2[x])), 2)
```

Comment: I want to implement using numpy and pandas as scikit learn takes more time executing it as it needs to compile the whole library.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

`csv.reader` returns **string** by default. You need to convert the appropriate items to floats.

Also, you can obtain a Pandas dataframe directly using

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

And get a Numpy array, if you like, using

```
data = df.values
```

and then operate on this data.

---

The first line of your csv is probably the header and you are not skipping it. So your first training instance is actually the strings that make up the header and you are trying to subtract strings in your `euclideanDistance` function.

Having said that, your code is very *unpythonic*.

For e.g.,

```
length = len(testInstance) - 1
for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
    dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
    distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
```

You don't need to pass `length` because that can be *looked up* using the `len` function inside `euclideanDistance`.

You can iterate over the instances in `trainingSet` directly

```
for x in trainingSet:
    dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, x, length)
    distances.append((x, dist))
```

or better

```
distances = [(x, euclideanDistance(testInstance, x) for x in trainingSet)]
```

Likewise,

```
neighbors = []
for x in range(k):
    neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
```

can just be

```
neighbors = [x[0] for x in distances[:k]]
```

Python also allows you to return multiple items at one time and it is extremely bad practice to return by reference as is commonly done in other languages. So

```
def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):
```

should be

```
def loadDataset(filename, split):
    trainingSet = []
    testSet = []
    # ...

    return trainingSet, testSet

trainingSet, testSet = loadDataset(filename, ',')
```

For this sort of application, you should avoid using Python list in this case and instead use Numpy arrays to store your data. This way many operations can be vectorized, giving tremendous speed up in performance.

For e.g., to compute distance between `testInstance` and `trainingSet`

```
# I'm deliberately converting them to numpy array but in general 
# you should keep them in this form right from the start
testInstance = np.asarray(testInstance).reshape(1, -1)[:-1] # Your last item is label. Ideally remove them at the beginning
trainingSet = np.vstack(trainingSet)[:, :-1] # Same case as above.

# Here we use broadcasting to obtain difference 
# between each row in trainingSet and testInstance
distances = np.linalg.norm(trainingSet - testInstance, axis=1)**2
```

If you are allowed/willing to use Scipy, then there are other opportunities to reduce the lines of code and speed up the operations.

Not only will writing your code this way give better performance, it is also more succinct and closer to the original mathematical expressions.

Comment: No, the first line of csv is not the header.

Comment: I'm from a statistics background so my python code is really dumb I'm a beginner programmer so my code may seem unpythonic Thanks for answer I'm figuring it out.